# How get the info of a element in webform email twig?

Tags: theming, webforms, 9

I'm on D9, theming a webform email.

I'm currently overriding the twig file, instead of using the configuration of the body in the email hanlder, because there are various conditional logic I've to check - e.g. if interface language is *en* print *element a* otherwise *element b*.

To create the required markup, I need to get the info of the elements: for example, for select elements, I need the *label* and the text of the option selected, not the raw value.

However, I can't find them using the webform_submission, as it seems to contain only the raw data put by the user.

For now, I've find this way to get the info I need, but I'd like to know if there's a more direct\better way to get them:

`webform-email-message-html--webform-id.html.twig`:

```
{% set submission_data =webform_submission.getData %}
{% set webform = handler.getWebform %}
{% set my_element_test = webform.getElementDecoded('element_id') %}
{% set option_label_test = my_element['#options']['options_id'] %}

{# todo print the markup for all elements #}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone needing this, doing this in the twig works:

```
{% set webform = webform_submission.getWebform %}
{% set webform_element = webform.getElement(key) %}
{% set submission_data =webform_submission.getData %}

//value = value of the specific element inside submission_data
{% if webform_element['#options'] is defined %}
  {{ webform_element['#options'][value] }}
{% else %}
  {{ value }}
{% endif %}
```

Doing a bit of code-diving, I've seen that `WebformOptionsHelper::getOptionText()` - called at some point by the code ran by Webform tokens' function - does a bit more complex logic to get the values, but at least for my case the above is sufficient.